# c# event on combobox using razor

Tags: c#, razor, eventhandler

I'm using a combobox on the layout view and i need to call a method on a controller when an index is changed

Here is what i have on _Layout.cshtml

```
        <select id="combo" OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server">
                <option> xxx</option>
                <option>yyy</option>
        </select>
```

And i call the method on controller

```
 public void IndexChanged(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(... ){

        }else{

        }
    }
```

But the program never reach the method, and i dont know why..Ideas?

I already saw other questions, but nothing works for me. I tried put the method on the view, create a method without params ... nothing works

Comment: where did you follow this code from?  And its a MVC application right?

Comment: I saw on other post on stack, and yes its a mvc apllication, sorry

Comment: well that post has totally misguided you.. there is no `runat="server"` in MVC.. no  `object o, EventArgs e` .. There is no connection between your server side code(c#) and client side code (HTML) in MVC.. its all seperated

Comment: Ok.. i added the runat="server", but how can i send the object and the eventargs on params? (from the view)

Comment: You should not send event object also.. You are mixing Webforms and MVC.. both are totally different except both use C# and some common namespaces..

Comment: So there is no way to call a method when i'm using events

Comment: You need to use ajax and jquery for this task.. Using jquery you can handle the click event.. and using ajax you can send data to server..

Comment: even using razor?

Comment: You cannot hit a class method.. you can hit a `ActionResult` of a `controller`.. You need to know the basics of MVC.. At the moment you are  thinking in webforms way

Comment: :) no problem..